# What effect does L-cysteine have in a growth medium on Lactobacillus and Bombilactobacillus found in bee species?

Tags: microbiology, growth-media

To cultivate Lactobacillus and Bombilactobacillus species we used MRS supplemented with 2% fructose in both aerobic and anaerobic conditions and also MRS supplemented with 2% fructose and 0.1% L-cysteine. The second medium showed significantly better growth in both conditions therefore we attributed this effect to L-cysteine. Could anyone explain why exactly this would have made a difference?

Comment: Welcome to the Biology Stack Exchange. Please take the [tour] and visit the [help] for more information on this site. Please also note the [homework](https://biology.stackexchange.com/help/homework) requirement, as this question sounds very much like easily answerable homework.